# Does the cosine of a matrix have a geometric (non power series) interpretation?

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry

You can adapt the power series definition of cosine to take in a matrix. Does this have a geometric interpretation/definition? Can it be used for various purposes? I actually have extended the matrix product to a broad class of manifolds, so I'm wondering how important this advance is.

Comment: https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Jacob_Wakem

Comment: I imagine the geometric interpretation would depend on precisely which adaptation you took.   For example, if you used the Euler identity as  your inspiration, that would be one thing.  If you literally just plugged a matrix into $1-x^2/2 + x^4/4! - \cdots$ that would be another.

Comment: @RyanBudney Apparently systems of differential equations can be solved using the cosine of a matrix. Wonder what you could solve with the cosine of a manifold.

Answer (score 1):

*Comment*
Maybe something comes from the differential equation ...
Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix.  The $C^2$ function
$y : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R^n$ satisfies the differential equation
$$
y''(t)+A^2 \big(y(t)\big)=0, \quad y(0)=y_0, y'(0)=0
$$
if and only if
$$
y(t) = \cos(tA) \big(y_0\big)
$$

Comment: As you say, this is a comment (in fact apparently in the same spirit as @Insulin's [earlier comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/425662/does-the-cosine-of-a-matrix-have-a-geometric-non-power-series-interpretation#comment1094189_425662)); it does not seem to be an answer.